# How do I uninstall/remove "Unity Websites Integration" from Firefox Extensions?

Tags: firefox, extension, websites

What package do I have to uninstall to remove the Firefox Extension entry "Unity Websites Integration"?

Answer (score 1):

Type `about:config` into the address bar

- Accept the "I solemnly swear i am up to no good" question;
- search for: unity
- finds: "ul.use_unity_menubar"  "user set"  "boolean"  "**true**",
- double click line to change to false: "ul.use_unity_menubar"  "user set"  "boolean"  "**false**"

restart firefox, boom, you have the menu back on the window.

If you don't know about `about:config`, google about:config or maybe "firefox about:config" or just put it in your firefox address bar: about:config as a website.  Like anything useful, about:config is dangerous.  That potential to do great harm also means it has the potential to great good.  Odd thing about useful stuff.

Answer (score 0):

A quick search in `synaptic` turned up the following package: `xul-ext-websites-integration`. So, presumably removing that will get rid of the entry.

Personally, though, if I wanted rid of it I'd much prefer to just disable it in the Extensions menu than uninstall it entirely (Firefox->Tools->Add-Ons->Extensions->Disable next to the unwanted extension); the websites-integration package has a couple of dependants (I believe that they are just to do with web apps, but it's still better to disable than uninstall, I'd say). Having a disabled entry in the extensions list shouldn't be that much of a worry.

Answer (score 0):

Just execute this in terminal:

sudo apt-get remove xul-ext-unity -y && sudo apt-get remove xul-ext-websites-integration -y